# Mod_rewrite is adding /var/www to the resulting URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have some problems with the Apache mod_rewrite rules. Whenever I try to go to `https://example.com//` (see double slashes at the end) it redirects to a 301 page but it's adding the location of the directory, i.e. `https://example.com/var/www/my-domain.com/html` which is not desirable.

Here is my `.htaccess` file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /views/pages/404.php

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?)/+(/\S+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) [L,R=404]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/{2,} [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^contact-us/?$ views/pages/contact.php [NC,L]
```

Same happens when I go to `https://example.com//contact-us`.

`https://example.com/contact-us//` is redirecting well to `https://example.com/contact-us` and `https://example.com//contact-uss` is redirecting well to the 404 page.

If one needs further information let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/{2,} [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [R=301,L]
> ```

You are missing the slash prefix on the *substitution*. This results in a relative-path substitution (since the `$1` backreference does not contain the slash prefix), to which mod_rewrite prefixes the directory-prefix (ie. `/var/www/example.com/html`). This would result in the malformed redirect you are seeing. The `RewriteRule` should be written as:

```
RewriteRule (.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

(The `^` anchor on the `RewriteRule` *pattern* is unnecessary here.)

However, the following redirect is also invalid:

> ```
> RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?)/+(/\S+) [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*) [L,R=404]
> ```

You are missing the *substitution* argument altogether. `[L,R=404]` will be seen as the *substitution* string (not the *flags*, as intended). This would also result in a malformed rewrite/redirect. The `RewriteRule` should be written as:

```
RewriteRule (.*) - [R=404]
```

Note the `-` (single hyphen) is used as the *substitution* argument (which is later ignored). When specifying a non-3xx response code, the `L` flag is implied.

---

However, I'm curious what it is you are trying to do here, as you appear to be "accepting" multiple slashes in one directive (by *reducing* them), but then rejecting multiple slashes in another directive (with a 404)? Why not reduce all sequences of multiple slashes wherever they occur in the URL-path?

For example, replace the following (modified code):

```
# Remove trailing slash from URL (except files and directories)
# >>> Why files? Files don't normally have trailing slashes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Reject multiple slashes later in the URL or 3+ slashes at the start of the URL
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?)/+(/\S+) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) - [R=404]

# Reduce multiple slashes at the start of the URL
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/{2,} [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

With something like the following (depending on requirements):

```
# Reduce sequences of multiple slashes to a single slash in the URL-path
# NB: This won't work to reduce slashes in the query string (if that is an issue)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //+
RewriteRule (.*) /$1 [R=302,L]

# Remove trailing slash from URL (except directories)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=302,L]
```

Note that I've reversed the directives so that slashes are reduced before the final trailing slash is removed.

Test with 302s to avoid caching issues. And clear your browser cache before testing.

**UPDATE:** If double slashes could ever (legitimately) occur in the *query string* portion of the URL then the above will result in a redirect loop since the *condition* checks for multiple slashes *anywhere* in the URL (including the query string), whereas the `RewriteRule` only reduces multiple slashes in the URL-path. If you need to allow multiple slashes in the query string then change the *CondPattern* from `//+` to `\s[^?]*//+` to specifically check the URL-path only, not the entire URL. In other words:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s[^?]*//+
RewriteRule (.*) /$1 [R=302,L]
```